# Orion-ld fails to establish a connection with the MongoDB Community Operator due to a connection string issue

Tags: mongodb, operator-keyword, fiware, fiware-orion

I am attempting to connect Orion-LD to the MongoDB Community Operator in a Kubernetes (k8s) environment, but I am encountering the following error:

```
time=Friday 06 Oct 15:25:17 2023.339Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=mongocInit.cpp[58]:mongocLog | msg=MONGOC[mongoc]: A '/' is required between the host list and any options.
time=Friday 06 Oct 15:25:17 2023.339Z | lvl=FATAL | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=mongocInit.cpp[294]:mongocInit | msg=Unable to connect to mongo(URI: mongodb://my-user:xxxx@orionld-mongodb-svc:27017?replicaSet=orionld-mongodb&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256&): Invalid host string in URI
```

Interestingly, when I use the standard Orion, this issue does not occur. In my view, there is an error in the connection string because a '/' is required between the host list and any options.

Could someone please assist me with this issue?

Here's the relevant part of my Kubernetes configuration:

```yaml
spec:
  containers:
  - name: orion
    image: fiware/orion-ld
    args: ["-dbhost","orionld-mongodb-svc:27017","-rplSet","orionld-mongodb","-dbuser","my-user","-dbpwd","xxxx","-dbAuthMech","SCRAM-SHA-256","-db","orion","-logLevel","INFO"]
    ports:
    - containerPort: 1026
```

I need Orion-ld to connect to the MongoDB Community Operator.

Comment: The issue was resolved using the following parameters:
`args: ["-dbURI", "mongodb+srv://my-user:xxxx@orionld-mongodb-svc.default.svc.cluster.local/admin?replicaSet=orionld-mongodb&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256&ssl=false"]`

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the "for some strange reason necessary" slash has been solved, see PR in Orion-LD's github